# How can I divide rows in the dataframe and rank them as new column?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
d = {'Rank': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'Name': ["apple", "banana", "grape", "orange", "plum", "blackberry"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.head()
```

And I want to get a new column "level" and based on the rank column, I want to have a new rank such as:
['High', 'Medium', 'Low'], so for my dataframe will look like this:

```
  Rank   Name    New Rank
0  1    apple     High
1  2    banana    High
2  3    grape     Medium
3  4    orange    Medium
4  5     plum     Low
5  6   blackberry Low
```

I'm not sure the name of this type of calculation(?) so I've been searching using the keywords such as "rank" and "divide new rank", and I wasn't able to find the right help. (I saw a lot of `.rank()` but that was not what I wanted..) What is the name of this process and how can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please figure out what is required and make an attempt to read about rank function

Comment: @AajKaal I read the rank function and as I mentioned in the post, rank is not the function  I was looking for.

Comment: You should at least have a criteria for High Low Medium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `cut` function, which essentially acts like a histogram labeler that you give custom labels to:

```py
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Rank': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
df['New Rank'] = pandas.cut(df['Rank'], bins=3, labels=['High', 'Medium', 'Low'])
```

```
   Rank New Rank
0     1     High
1     2     High
2     3   Medium
3     4   Medium
4     5      Low
5     6      Low
```